# How do I separate the object I want in a sum function in R?

Tags: r, sum

I am trying to calculate pooled standard deviation `s_pooled` in `R` and I am trying to use the `sum()` function. Do I separate the objects I want summed by a comma `,`?

This is,

```
s_pooled <- sqrt(sum((19-1)*varPacific, (22-1)*varTasman)/(19 + 22 - 2))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look at the documentation!

There are examples at the bottom of most all the basic R function documentation. At `?sum` you can see the following:

```
## Pass a vector to sum, and it will add the elements together.
sum(1:5)

## Pass several numbers to sum, and it also adds the elements.
sum(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

## In fact, you can pass vectors into several arguments, and everything gets added.
sum(1:2, 3:5)

## If there are missing values, the sum is unknown, i.e., also missing, ....
sum(1:5, NA)
## ... unless  we exclude missing values explicitly:
sum(1:5, NA, na.rm = TRUE)
```

So the answer is **yes, you can use a comma to separate terms** as in the second example. Or you can put things in a vector and sum the vector as in the first example. Or you can do a combination of both, as in the third example.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that `example(sum)` can bring all this into the console

Comment: Thank you for your help! I was asking because I have looked at everything but was trying to compare with the function just using the + sign and was not getting the same result. in the meanwhile I have found the missing parentheses.